# How to find second order derivative

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Suppose we have that $dp=u dt+s dz$, where $dz$ is brownian motion.
What would be $d^2 p$? that is, the second derivative under ito calculus.

Comment: you are right. possibly you can proceed by analogy with 2D, taking a total differential of a sorts to get $d^2 p = u (dt)^2 + s (dz)^2$ and maybe using $dz^2 = dt$, but not sure how.

Comment: That did not answer the question. Does anyone know the answer to the question?

Comment: I'd recommend you refrain from commenting if you don't know the answer, especially you asked me several questions that was not productive at all and was taking up other people's time.

Comment: when i posted an answer, i made a mistake in calculations, so i thought i well knew what the answer was. as for this comment, it is not an answer, just a suggestion along which lines i would think...

Comment: That's why I asked you to post the answer first right off the bat.